# Slicing PNG vs PSD for web

Tags: css, html

I'm learning web design and I have come across a website called [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com)
The issue is that it doesn't obviously generate PSD but it produces PNG.
Based on my experience with developers, PSD is what they use.
My question is it possible to use PNG? Is it any easier?

Thanks

Comment: A PNG would give them an overview on what the final product design should look. A PSD also gives them access to the theme source, if you want to call it like that. With the PSD they are able to take elements from the design, whereas a PNG would just be a preview. Sketch is a vector type of program, I personally haven't used it to design websites in it, just create vectors for icons. Think of Sketch as what Fireworks is for Adobe.

Comment: PSD cannot be used directly on website. Always use web-optimized PNG / JPEG / GIF ( In Photoshop, Save for Web & Devices )

Comment: Maybe SVG is the best approach :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that **`PSD`** is a file format for Photoshop and **`PNG`** is an image file format.

You cannot use **`PSD`** for web purposes. Designers/Developer slice the PSD to their **`JPEG/PNG`** format or even **`CSS`** for web usage.